# How to pass entered login(email) details to another ViewController - programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having problems with the code I did with some tutorials.

My main concern is that I cannot find how to pass/expose entered "email/login" data in other view controller. (for this time it's called homeViewController)

Login or signup is set with Firebase if this changes anything.

```
@IBAction func LoginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // TODO: Validate Text Fields

    // Create cleaned versions of the text field
    let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    // Signing in the user
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            // Couldn't sign in
            self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
        }
        else {

            let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.HomeViewController) as? HomeViewController

            self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
    }
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is add the data to the view controller that you instantiate.

First make sure that `HomeViewController` has a property called `email` and `password`:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
}
```

Then, when you instantiate your `homeViewController` via `let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.HomeViewController) as? HomeViewController`, simply set the properties in the following lines:

```swift
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            // Couldn't sign in
            self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
        }
        else {

            var homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.HomeViewController) as? HomeViewController
            homeViewController.email = self.email
            homeViewController.password = self.password

            self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
    }
```